# @Requires annotation of Seam Solder should receive a string or a class?

Tags: java, annotations, java-ee-6, seam3, deltaspike

[Seam Solder documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e176) says that the `@Requires` annotation requires an array of `Class` objects as a parameter. However, when I try to use it (from Seam Solder 3.0.0.Final API artifact - not the impl artifact, it is worth noting) Eclipse informs me the annotation expects an array of strings. Some source code I have found also [indicates the annotation requires strings](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org%24nexus%24content%24repositories%24releases@org.jboss.seam.solder%24seam-solder@3.0.0.Beta1@org%24jboss%24seam%24solder%24core%24Requires.java).

So, is this a bug in Solder documentation? Also, what is the expected string for the annotation? (I suppose it is the fully qualified type name, but I would like to make it sure and, anyway, it would be good to have such a reference in the web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peeking in the source code [reveals](https://github.com/seam/solder/blob/develop/api/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/solder/core/Requires.java) that Eclipse is right. The Seam 3 documentation is not always correct, unfortunately.

Filing a JIRA issue or starting a pull request would be the perfect open source community attitude...